# SBOM file generation for flutter apps

Tags: flutter, security, cicd

I'm interested on setting up a step in a CI/CD flow that will scan a flutter app and create an SBOM (software bill of materials) file. I checked that there is the [syft tool](https://github.com/anchore/syft) which supports dart language but wondering if anyone used this or there is an alternative tool for such purposes?

Answer (score 1):

We were looking into the [SBOM](https://pub.dev/packages/sbom) package but it actually doesn't look into the packages, yet. They claim to implement CycloneDx support in future releases, though.

Instead, we are now using Google's [OSV scanner](https://github.com/google/osv-scanner) which supports Pub. It doesn't come with a License checker, yet.